# With Wordpress + Visual Composer, how to restrict a user to change some content in a page?

Tags: plugins

Sorry if it's not the right place to post that but I did not find better.

I know in Wordpress, it's possible to restrict users to change pages or remove items from the menu.

But is it possible to restrict them to change a content in a page? As I am using [Visual Composer](https://vc.wpbakery.com/) I think this feature may be related to this.

I did find there is a role manager page with Visual Composer but the configuration isn't deep enough to have that level of restriction.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such granular control. The only possible way around it is to use shortcodes that insert content from other "posts" and restrict the access to those posts.

Comment: That's a good solution! I think it can feed my needs! Do you know if there is any documentation on this subject (not on shortcodes but on this particular process)?

Comment: sorry no, I actually never heard of anyone trying to do that before, so you might be a pioneer with that :)